# Jupyterlab Package Directory

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, jupyter-lab

I'm having trouble importing pypyodbc in a jupyterlab notebook. I'm able to import it in a shell and even "old" jupyter notebooks. I've tried installing it via `pip`, `conda`, and manually. When I run `!{sys.executable} -m pip install pypyodbc` in the notebook it just shows:

> Requirement already satisfied: pypyodbc in
> c:~\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.3-py3.6.egg
> (1.3.3)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
> ~\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
> (from pypyodbc) (39.1.0)

I can import other packages just fine, but pypyodbc isn't working. What is the default package directory for jupyterlab, and how can I point it to a specific directory to import packages from?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have multiple versions of Python running on your computer and Jupyter is selecting a version that does not have that package.  To figure out what version of Python is running in your notebook do this inside Jupyter:

```
import os
import inspect
inspect.getfile(os)
```

Then you can run pip on that specific version:

```
python3.6 -m pip install pypyodbc
```

Alternatively, you can try to uninstall the package and reinstall via pip if it still doesn't work.

Comment: It points to the Python under the anaconda directory so I would assume it would import from `/lib/site-packages`. The reinstall was unsuccessful as well :(